# I'm looking for this FPC connector

Tags: board, fpc

I'm looking for this board, but I don't know the correct name:
[image]
[image]

Anyone knows the name?

Comment: ZIF + Pin Pintch --> Google --> Search until the picture matches. Or: Ask a distributor by giving the pin pitch. or... etc etc.

Comment: You're looking for much more than the FPC, if you're trying to find that board.  It's got a chop-on-board!

Comment: You haven't even said what that board is supposed to do!  And, in the title you're looking for a connector, but in the question you're looking for a board.  Closing this mess.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/1442849?k=&pv69=352&FV=1b4c0008%2Cfff40016%2Cfff80421%2C1600012&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) Digikey search for 26-position, FPC, top-conductor connectors. You didn't provide images of both sides of the flex cable or a picture of the connector with a ruler, so I can't be sure what pin pitch the connector you have is.

To search through the available FPC connectors by type, contact number, contact pitch, etc., consider [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/connectors/ffc-fpc-flat-flex-connectors)'s or [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Connectors/FFC-FPC/FFC-FPC-Connectors/_/N-axjq6/)'s selection of board-mount connectors.

If you can provide more information/pictures, your specific connector could be more easily identified. However, do not expect to find the exact same part number as the one you have, just one that is *probably* compatible.